# Strange material, Bydrogen

Tags: charge, fermions, bosons, metamaterials

Let's take a hypothetical scenario in which you manage to make a meta material in which the bulk of the mass is made of by a central negative nucleus and that has a single spin 1 boson whizzing around it as if they were electrons, and let's call this material Bydrogen. Assume that the ratio between the nucleus mass and the boson is the same as that between the electron and the proton, ie the nucleus has a mass 1836.152 bigger than the Boson.

I want to understand what kind of properties Bydrogen would have.

The energy levels of such a material would be not that different to that of Hydrogen, of course taking in consideration for the new reduced mass $\mu$, since the Schrodinger equation would look exactly the same and therefore also the orbitals would be the same. That also means that the atomic spectra of such a material would be very similar to that of hydrogen since it would only get excited by photons with a certain energy given by the spacing of the energy levels.

I imagine that the first difference would arise when you turn to the chemistry of such a material. Hydrogen is in its most stable configuration of $H_2$ because if you were to add a third Hydrogen atom, then that electron would have to go in the first excited state(due to the Pauli exclusion principle, and therefore it would be at a higher energy and so it is less stable than $H_2$. In the case of of Bydrogen it's most stable configuration would probably include a much higher number of Nuclei since Bosons are not restricted by the Pauli exclusion principle and could go on to keep on filling the lowest energy configuration.

How many atoms could be bound together before it becomes energetically unstable to keep on adding more? Is there a limit to such a number?

Feel free to comment any different properties that the material would have compared to the classical Hydrogen.

Comment: How would you propose getting such a massive negative nucleus? And how would your negative nucleus be kept together? Some variation of the residual strong force? The obvious difference to normal hydrogen would in MRI due to the huge mass this negative nucleus possesses.

Comment: I propose no way, that's the reason its a hypothetical situation. Yes it would be something like the strong force so that the analogy with hydrogen works better.

Comment: *the proton, being a Boson...* No. Protons have spin 1/2 and are therefore fermions.

Comment: oh snap i got confused, sorry about that, i'll change my question now

Comment: It seems that nuclear charge screening is the important issue here. When you add more bosons the way they screen the protons will diverge from hydrogen. But even the hydrogen molecule seems to be slightly tricky to analyse: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.jpca.7b08963?src=recsys